# can Excel take data from a Text Cell and place it into a Formula Cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am tracking several stocks, and saving their chart data in separate spreadsheets titled by their ticker symbol (i.e. aapl.xlsx, goog.xlsx, etc...). I want to have a single spreadsheet that I can change the text in a cell to the ticker symbol so that it will reference the proper file for that stock, thereby allowing me to pull a different stock's data each time I change the cell. All of the data is on a page called "1", so I need to be able to have a way to reference a text cell and input it into a formula such as:

```
=rounddown([XXXX.xlsx]1!D4-[XXXX.xlsx]1!H4,2)*[XXXX.xlsx]1!B4
```

where XXXX is the text that I input to a cell on my new spreadsheet. I've been trying to use different ways to reference it using the INDIRECT( function, but I haven't been able to get that to work yet.

Is Excel capable of taking a text input and placing it into a formula? if possible how would this be achieved?

Comment: Have you read the help document on [linking workbooks?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-HP010102338.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of depends on whether the cell you are referencing is a static cell (e.g., the value is *always* in `A4` or `'Grade 11 Data'!A4`).

If not, then you do need to use the INDIRECT() function. You would use it like `INDIRECT("K"&A4)` where `A4` contained a row number, say 9.   Then it resolves to `INDIRECT("K9")` and that would then resolve to the cell `K9`.

You can also use stuff like `INDIRECT("'Grade 11 Data'!K"&A4)`,
which would resovle to `INDIRECT("'Grade 11 Data'!K9")`,
which would resolve to cell `'Grade 11 Data'!K9`.

An example for INDIRECT is that I had a sheet where I would enter a lot number and it would reference a different cell depending on the lot number I entered (A4 if I enter 4, A7 if I enter 7, A8 if 8, ....) to find shipping values and strings that vary depending on which lot I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all your stock files open?  You will need to do that.  According to [the Excel 2007 Help for the INDIRECT function](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetId=HP100624139990&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL&Version=12&queryid=&respos=1&HelpID=xlmain11%2Echm60196),

> If ref_text refers to another workbook (an external reference), the other workbook must be open. 
>   If the source workbook is not open, `INDIRECT` returns the `#REF!` error value.